# Nvidia 8500 GT card problem

Tags: graphics-card

I recently got a problem with my nvidia 8500 gt 1gb graphic card. Sometimes my monitor detects it and sometimes it does not display at all. I have noticed two things 1) When my monitor detects the graphic card windows hangs after 5-15 minutes 2) When monitor does not display I can access computer remotely but then system does not become unresponsive.

Any solution?

Comment: It's not your monitor detecting it, its your pc.  Has the issue been there since you installed it?  What OS is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When monitor does not display I can access computer remotely but then system does not become unresponsive.

That most certainly means it's something to do with the card, because (unless you're using VNC) remote access programs don't even touch the graphics card, sending all the draw instructions instead.

Try downloading drivers:

- [Windows 7](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7-winvista-32bit-258.96-whql-driver.html)
- [Windows XP](http://www.nvidia.com/object/winxp-258.96-whql-driver.html)

You can find drivers for other Windowses too on nVidia's [Download Page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).